# facet Filter in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

[image]

Is there filter in sapui5/fiori shown in image. I searched a lot but did not found any. Thx

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your question - could you explain it a bit more in detail?

Comment: I added a test page to my answer if you wanted to play around with the suggested control. If something is missing or unclear, please let me know. Otherwise, please read ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're looking for is *Value Help Dialog*:

<kbd>[image: sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog]</kbd>

Be aware that the module is available **only in SAPUI5**. It's not open sourced.

---

## Resources

- [API reference](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog/)
- [Test page](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/comp/valuehelpdialog/ValueHelpDialog.html) (Click on the value help button of the input field in order to open the dialog)
- [UX guideline](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/value-help-dialog/)